# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode =0x0) on Swift when working with multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array, swift, exc-bad-instruction

I get this error when I try to create an array which contain arrays with enums.

To illustrate better here's the code:

```
let block1:Form[] = [Form.Circle, Form.Rectangle, Form.Triangle]
let block2:Form[] = [Form.Rectangle, Form.Circle, Form.Triangle]
let block3:Form[] = [Form.Rectangle, Form.Triangle, Form.Circle]
let block4:Form[] = [Form.Circle, Form.Triangle, Form.Rectangle]
let block5:Form[] = [Form.Triangle, Form.Circle, Form.Rectangle]
let block6:Form[] = [Form.Triangle, Form.Rectangle, Form.Circle]
var allBlocks:(Form[][])!
```

These are the arrays holding the enums and the last one will hold these arrays.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

          allBlocks = [block1, block2, block3, block4, block5, block6] //Error here
...
}
```

The error occurs when I try to assign the value to allBlocks

If I change the code to this I get no error:

```
let block1:Form[] = [Form.Circle, Form.Rectangle, Form.Triangle]
let block2:Form[] = [Form.Rectangle, Form.Circle, Form.Triangle]
let block3:Form[] = [Form.Rectangle, Form.Triangle, Form.Circle]
let block4:Form[] = [Form.Circle, Form.Triangle, Form.Rectangle]
let block5:Form[] = [Form.Triangle, Form.Circle, Form.Rectangle]
let block6:Form[] = [Form.Triangle, Form.Rectangle, Form.Circle]

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

         var allBlocks = [block1, block2, block3, block4, block5, block6] //No error
...
}
```

But then I can't access the allBlocks variable in another place.

EDIT: In case it helps

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Runtime error when using CoreFoundation objects in a swift NSObject subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997536/runtime-error-when-using-corefoundation-objects-in-a-swift-nsobject-subclass)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a Swift compiler bug; the crash was due to an attempt to execute an illegal x86 instruction, so either the compiler generated invalid code or generated a branch to something that wasn't code at all or wasn't the beginning of an instruction.

Presumably you're beta-testing Xcode, so, if you don't already have an Apple Developer Connection account that lets you file bugs on Radar^W[Apple Bug Reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com), open an account, and then file a bug.  (Apple may have given details on this as part of the Xcode download.)

Comment: As an aside, a bad instruction is normally inserted deliberately by assertion failures in Apple's libraries to halt the program, so that's the usual source of this exception. But yes, in this case with a beta compiler there's always the chance of an *actual* bad instruction, I suppose...

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error code in C on OS X, so it's not nessicarily related to Swift.

Comment: It could be a bug in the code generator, which is shared by the C, C++, Objective-C/Objective-C++, and Swift compilers.

Comment: @Matt Gibson If the assertion failures turn into calls to `abort()`, you'll get "EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)" rather than "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode =0x0)".

Answer (score 0):

I think it is no longer an issue in XCode6 beta 6. Here is my test code:

```
enum Form: Int {
    case Circle=1
    case Rectangle
    case Triangle
}


func testEnumArray () {
    let block1:[Form] = [Form.Circle, Form.Rectangle, Form.Triangle]
    let block2:[Form] = [Form.Rectangle, Form.Circle, Form.Triangle]
    let block3:[Form] = [Form.Rectangle, Form.Triangle, Form.Circle]
    let block4:[Form] = [Form.Circle, Form.Triangle, Form.Rectangle]
    let block5:[Form] = [Form.Triangle, Form.Circle, Form.Rectangle]
    let block6:[Form] = [Form.Triangle, Form.Rectangle, Form.Circle]
    var allBlocks = [block1, block2, block3, block4, block5, block6]
    println(allBlocks)

}
```

It does not throw exception anymore.

In addition, there is a syntax change since the question was posted:

Instead of `let block6:Form[]` we need to write `let block6:[Form]`