# Swift, SpriteKit and multidimensional arrays with CGPoint

Tags: multidimensional-array, swift, sprite-kit, ios8, xcode6

I get an error when using a multidimensional array with `CGPoint` in a property at a `SKSpriteNode` derived class. **Only under these circumstances.**

Error is:

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

- I tried with `double` → worked
- I tried with `CGPoint` as a variable inside the function → worked
- I tried the failing code with a class not derived from `SKSpriteNode` → worked

Xcode 6.0 beta 2

Any ideas?

---

#### Here is my test code:

```
import SpriteKit

class TestSprite: SKSpriteNode {
   
    var myOuterArray = Array<Array<CGPoint>>()
    var myOuterDoubleArray = Array<Array<Double>>()
    
    init()  {
        super.init(texture:nil, color:UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeZero)
        self.testWithInnerArray()
        self.testWithOuterArray()
        self.testWithOuterDoubleArray()
    }
    
    // breaks
    func testWithOuterArray(){
        myOuterArray.append(Array(count:1, repeatedValue:CGPoint())) // << ERROR!
        println("myOuterArray.count : \(myOuterArray.count)")
    }

    // works
    func testWithOuterDoubleArray(){
        myOuterDoubleArray.append(Array(count:1, repeatedValue:Double()))
        println("myOuterDoubleArray.count : \(myOuterDoubleArray.count)")
    }
    
    // works
    func testWithInnerArray(){
        var myInnerArray = Array<Array<CGPoint>>()
        myInnerArray.append(Array(count:1, repeatedValue:CGPoint()))
        println("myInnerArray.count : \(myInnerArray.count)")
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXC\_BAD\_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC\_I386\_INVOP,subcode =0x0) on Swift when working with multi-dimensional arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223321/exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-i386-invop-subcode-0x0-on-swift-when-working-wit)

Comment: Your code works fine for me. I believe this is a Swift compiler bug.

Comment: I just verified the steps on iOS 8, Seed 3 (Build 12A4318c). I can still experiencing the issue. Did you run the code @pasta12?

Comment: I tried in a playground and it doesn't work for me either. Only the `testWithOuterArray()` function like you said.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Runtime error when using CoreFoundation objects in a swift NSObject subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997536/runtime-error-when-using-corefoundation-objects-in-a-swift-nsobject-subclass)

Comment: it works fine with Xcode Version 6.0 (6A280e)  (playground test) (just adding override to the init method and the init(coder...) also.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed in a later release of Xcode. Problem doesn't occur any more.