# Array as an instance variable crashes when trying to store CGColor type elements (Xcode 6 beta 4)

Tags: swift

The last line of `buildPalette()` crashes with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_IVOP, sub code = 0x0). It's ok when I use a different type, like `Int` instead of `CGColor`.

Curiously, I can use a local variable for the array and fill it with colours, but then it crashes with the same message when I try to return it from `buildPalette()`.

```
@objc class Palette {
  var palette: [CGColor]

  init() {
    palette = [CGColor]()
    buildPalette()
  }

  func buildPalette() {

    let rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    // omitting the loop for simplicity
    let color = CGColorCreate(rgb, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
    palette.append(color)   // crashes here
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24997536/2446155

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** As  `Maciej Trybiło 1` has commented this issue is fixed in `Xcode Beta 5`

You are using `CGColor` in array so it is not able to properly convert(bridged to `objective c`) in swift `AnyObject` array.When you use `CGColor` in array it is not directly covertable in swift as `AnyObject` within array so that cause runtime error while working with objective c classes.You need to define your `var palette` as `[AnyObject]` to proper conversion between `CoreGraphics`  to `swift` or you can use `UIColor`.

From Swift [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html)

> When you bridge from a Swift array to an NSArray object, the
>   elements in the Swift array must be AnyObject compatible. For example,
>   a Swift array of type Int[] contains Int structure elements. The Int
>   type is not an instance of a class, but because the Int type bridges
>   to the NSNumber class, the Int type is AnyObject compatible.
>   Therefore, you can bridge a Swift array of type Int[] to an NSArray
>   object. **If an element in a Swift array is not AnyObject compatible, a
>   runtime error occurs when you bridge to an NSArray object.**
>
> You can also create an NSArray object directly from a Swift array literal, following the same bridging rules outlined above. When you
>   explicitly type a constant or variable as an NSArray object and assign
>   it an array literal, Swift creates an NSArray object instead of a
>   Swift array.

So you need to make `CGColor` compatible with `AnyObject`.So below code will work fine.

```
@objc class Palette {
    var palette: [AnyObject]

    init() {
        palette = [AnyObject]()
        buildPalette()
    }

    func buildPalette() {

        let rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

        // omitting the loop for simplicity
        let color:CGColorRef = CGColorCreate(rgb, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
        palette.append(color)   // crashes here
    }
}
```

**Above method works with `CGColor` but You can use `UIColor` instead of `CGColor`and can convert your `CGColor` by `UIColor(CGColor: CGColor?)`.**

Comment: "You are using CGColor in array so it is not able to properly convert in swift AnyObject." I don't understand what you mean by this. `CGColor` seems compatible with `AnyObject` to me.

Comment: @newacct if we declare palette[CGColor] and add a CGColor to it then swift is not able to convert this array as palette[AnyObject] because of CGColor implicitly.So we need to declare it as AnyObject which makes coversion explicitly.From docs:`If an element in a Swift array is not AnyObject compatible, a runtime error occurs when you bridge to an NSArray object.`This seems to bug to me as if you assign CGColor to AnyObject it works fine but converting CGColor array to AnyObject array will cause runtime error because it is not able to covert array properly.

Comment: Thanks, codester, AnyObject worked, but now beta 5 fixed it and CGColor works too!